# How to animate a slide from left on a View in Android

Tags: android, animation, view

I have a view. I will set the view left out of the screen. Now I want to animate a slide from left to the screen on this view. How can do this in Android?

This is my View

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/mView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the sample code for move a textview with animation from x position as 0 to centre of the screen width.

```
    ObjectAnimator textViewAnimation= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textView,"X",0f,width/2);
    textViewAnimation.setDuration(2000);
    textViewAnimation.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this tutorial about animations https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Animations

Here is the example code to move a textview in x-axis 100 points. You can animate your own view like this.

```java
 ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textView, "translationX", 100f);
 animation.setDuration(1000);
 animation.start();
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for you quick response. I'm trying your code out and have a question. What is "translationX" means? I'm gettin an error "Could not find property setter method"

Comment: It is a property animation. You can read more about it on: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation or https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Animations#property-animations. In this sample code, the "textview" has a translation animation from x position with a duration of 1 second